# how to change the master details relationship field type

Tags: administration

there are 2 objects contacts & accounts under that mailing address(contacts) & billing address(accounts) fields are there. they are in master detail relationship.Whenever i am filling mailing address it is updating on the billing address field which i don't want.so is it possible to remove this auto updating ?

Comment: I guess there is any process builder or any custom development is copying the fields.

Comment: This is not standard Salesforce behaviour - it can be created by a number of options - 1. a Workflow rule, 2. a Process Builder or 3. Apex code (trigger) - look to see if any of those exist in your Salesforce Org that could be causing this, they can then be disabled.

Comment: @DaveHumm, seems legit, but add it in an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not standard Salesforce behaviour - it can be created by a number of options -

1. Workflow rule
2. Process Builder
3. Apex code (trigger)

look to see if any of those exist in your Salesforce Org that could be causing this, they can then be disabled.